How to download exe file from github using python
I have searched a lot for answers, but for the exe file format, I still cannot do it.
This is my code:
import requests
import base64
import shutil

def download_file_from_github(repo_owner, repo_name, file_path, access_token):
    
    api_url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/contents/{file_path}"
    # Send a GET request to the API with the access token
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, stream=True, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        content = response.json().get("content", "")
        decoded_content = base64.b64decode(content)
        return decoded_content
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve file. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace these with your specific repository details and access token
    repo_owner = "NguyenDucQuan12"
    repo_name = "Update_app"
    file_path = "QSV-VN/app/QSV-VN.exe"
    access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

    file_content = download_file_from_github(repo_owner, repo_name, file_path, access_token)
    if file_content:
        # Do something with the file content, such as save it to disk
        with open("QSV-VN.exe", "wb") as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file_content, f)
        print("File downloaded successfully.")

how can I download files in exe format, I upload it with git lfs because it exceeds 100mb
Other answers almost all do not have exe, is downloading files in exe format allowed?

What happens if you use this code?

@mkrieger1 My file is 325mb, but when run it is only 1kb. when I change the code, the result is still the same if response.status_code == 200:         return response and f.write(file_content.content)
